# how do i make my localhost backup website work?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, xampp, localhost

Help! I was building a wordpress site locally using localhost xampp and xampp started giving me issues. So i made a backup of my website folder in htdocs and uninstalled xampp, then reinstalled. Now i am copy and pasting my backup folder back into htdocs and it is telling me page not found! :( I re-created database in my phpmyadmin so that even that was identical to the previous database before uninstalling. Someone help me please i don't know what to do i had alot of content and cannot re-build from scatch :(

Comment: Hi, do you mean you have your database restored to how it was before after re-installing xampp?

Comment: @hiew1 yes exactly :( I want my website as how it was before before i uninstalled xampp

Comment: What errors do you see in the "Logs" ? On XAMPP control panel, you have 4 buttons for each row and the first row should be "Apache", and the second row should be "MySQL". If you click on the fourth button on each row what error messages are there?

Answer (score 0):

All the pages, posts, categories, tags media etc are created in database. So, if you have not backed up your database prior to un-install xamp, you will not get the content back. You will have to create them again. Next time when you do such things, please make sure to get a file backup (of your httdocs or www) and also a backup of the database too.